# Thread Yielding Before Async-Await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Before the introduction of `async-await` programming into C#, how was one able to put a network request into another thread and yield execution time back to the CPU until a response is received so that this thread will not waste CPU time?

Because when CPU allocates time to this thread and thread sits idle waiting for a response, that would be a waste of CPU time, right?

Comment: A blocked thread does not use CPU!

Comment: @PauloMorgado It doesn't use CPU but does the OS switch to another thread in queue when it sees this thread being blocked or does it wait until the allocated time slice for this thread finishes?

Comment: It doesn't spin. The OS assigns the CPU to another thread.

Answer (score 2):

In several ways, however [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm) was the go-to for this type of *Asynchrony*

> An asynchronous operation that uses the IAsyncResult design pattern is
>   implemented as two methods named `BeginOperationName` and
>   `EndOperationName` that begin and end the *Asynchronous Operation*
>   `OperationName` respectively. For example, the `FileStream` class provides
>   the `BeginRead` and `EndRead` methods to *Asynchronously* read bytes from a
>   file. These methods implement the asynchronous version of the Read
>   method.

To answer your question

> Because when CPU allocates time to this thread and thread sits idle
>   waiting for a response, that would be a waste of CPU time, right?

No blocking a thread and waiting for a completion port to call back doesn't cause CPU cycles to run away, however polling on a thread will.

There is a lot to how this works, however an example use can be seen here

**Example of usage**

```
private static void TestWrite()
{ 
   // Must specify FileOptions.Asynchronous otherwise the BeginXxx/EndXxx methods are
   // handled synchronously.
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(Program.FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
      FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

   string content = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
   byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

   // Begins to write content to the file stream.
   Console.WriteLine("Begin to write");
   fs.BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, Program.OnWriteCompleted, fs);
   Console.WriteLine("Write queued");
}

private static void OnWriteCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{ 
   // End the async operation.
   FileStream fs = (FileStream)asyncResult.AsyncState;
   fs.EndWrite(asyncResult);

   // Close the file stream.
   fs.Close();
   Console.WriteLine("Write completed");

   // Test async read bytes from the file stream.
   Program.TestRead();
}
```

Comment: Looking at the reference you provided, your example demonstrates EAP, not APM right? Because there seems to be no polling.

Comment: @JohnL. not quite, *EAP* is the  `MethodAsync(...)` and `CancelAsync(...)` pairs. There's usually a Completed event. Think of the `BackgroundWorker` for this pattern.